# creating a minimal HTTP server with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

While I'm familiar with both HTTP servers and event loops, I'm having some trouble grasping the inner workings of Python's [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

As a learning exercise, I've been trying to write a minimal HTTP server (just echoing out the request method, URI, headers and body), without additional dependencies. I've looked into [aiohttp](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp) and [aiowsgi](https://github.com/gawel/aiowsgi) for reference, but having trouble understanding what's going on there - in part because the perceived complexity of protocols, transports etc. is a bit overwhelming. So I'm currently stuck because I don't quite know where to begin.

Is it naive to expect this to be just a few lines of code to establish the connection, consume the incoming text stream and send back another text stream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take a look on [picoweb](https://github.com/pfalcon/picoweb) as example of very simple (and very limited) HTTP server.

But, sure, when you'll try to implement full-feature web server you will get something like aiohttp -- HTTP is complex (even maybe complicated) standard.

Comment: Thanks - that's quite close to what I was looking for. `start_server` in particular was the missing piece for me.

Comment: Sure. Trivial examples are good for learning.
But as co-author of *aiohttp* I guess to use [aiohttp.web](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/v0.12.0/web.html) for production code.

Comment: Nevermind, picoweb does not run on current CPython, with the last update two years ago - that's not useful.